# Oracle shared pool - read and write

Tags: oracle

i'm reading the book "Oracle Database Transactions and Locking Revealed" .
In Chapter 3: Locks, Latches, and Mutexes i have found this text: "We need
to latch the shared pool to parse SQL statements, and we need to latch the shared pool
because it is a shared data structure, and we cannot modify it while others are reading it
and we cannot read it while it is being modified."
So if i have 10 request to write some sql statements in Shared Pool and 1000 to read some sql then the read / write actions cannot be made concurrencial ? even if they are different sqls? isn't it too much overhead?

What is the problem if i want to write a sql (Sql1) into Shared Pool and at the same time i want to read a sql (Sql 2) from Shared Poll?

Comment: The latch taken is extremely fleeting, it's only to gain exclusive access to a section of memory, divided into hash buckets. Under normal conditions this isn't a concurrency issue. It only becomes a problem when someone gets stuck in parse for some reason (generally a bug). That will hold up other parses. Oracle has a slew of methods for improving concurrency on the shared pool, like 7 different subpools each protected with their own latch, each further divided into sub-pool "durations", a private session cursor cache in UGA (non-shared) memory, etc..

Comment: Sql1 - read, Sql2 - write, Sql3 - read. why these 3 sqls must be processed sequentially? Why can't they be processed at the same time?

Comment: Because it's shared memory. You can't protect a shared memory address without serialization. Otherwise one process could be reading it and another overwriting it at the same time, messing up the reader. The "readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers" mantra applies to data in tables, not to SGA memory structures. But because of the various mechanisms Oracle has built into improving concurrency, this really isn't an issue anyone has to worry about. It's so fleeting it might as well be truly concurrent. A bug leading to a stuck parse is about your only concern.

Comment: ok, thank you, can you add your explanations as an answer?

Comment: Migrated to an answer. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a multi-processor system, shared memory must be protected by a serialization mechanism of some kind or other. Otherwise one process could be reading it and another overwriting it at the same time, messing up the reader. The Oracle mantra "readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers" applies to data in tables (accomplished via consistent reads involving rollback segments), not to SGA memory structures which have no such mechanism.

But this is not a problem. The latch taken is extremely fleeting, it's only to gain exclusive access to a section of memory, divided into hash chain buckets to increase concurrency. Under normal conditions this isn't an issue. It only becomes a problem when someone gets stuck in parse for some reason (generally a bug). That will hold up other parses for SQLs that hash to the same hash bucket.

Oracle has a slew of methods for improving concurrency on the shared pool, like 7 different subpools each protected with their own latch, each further divided into sub-sub-pool "durations", a private session cursor cache in UGA (non-shared) memory, etc.. as a result, we normally don't run into noticeable performance issues due to shared pool latches. Under a bug situation or extreme/abusive load on the shared pool, yes you can have issues, but it generally isn't something to be concerned about.

Answer (score 1):

Do not take it for granted - I did not see Oracle's source code. This is only how I do imagine how it works.

Latch is locking memory structure within another structure. Originally everything inside Oracle was guarded by latches. Latches do remember previous structures value, so if anything goes wrong, `pmon` is able to revert back data structure into correct state. Also Latches have access counter which can be used by wait-interface to generate performance reports. Latches are implemented by instruction like "compare and exchange" executed in a loop. Waiting on a Latch is active.

Mutex is more modern way of locking. Mutexes are accelerated by HW+OS. Mutex is an entry point into a function. So when you have function called "allocate_some_bytes_in_sga()" only one process/thread can enter this function at time. Waiting in Mutex is passive.

Both Latches and Mutexes can be requested/held in shared or exclusive mode.

It is not easy to say which approach is better or worse. For example early version of Oracle's result cache, the access to result cache was guarded by a single Mutex, this resulted into serious concurrency problems, when result cache was also used by parser itself.
On contrary buffer cache is guarded by several Latches and each process has to acquire them one by one, to the change for blocking is lowered.